# bind_param with mysql in query accepting only the first value in the list

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, parameterization

I am using MySQL and PHP.

I tried to parameterize the queries using bind_param. Now I need to pass a list of integers to the parameterised IN Query.

I have tried with the below query:

```
select id,date,
  sum(value) as distance ,
  (select number from table2 where id=id) as Number
from Table1 where id in (1777,1778,1779)
```

But it is returning only the result for the first value in the list (`1777`).

How can I get the result for all the entries (`1777,1778,1779`) in the list?

Comment: what is `where id=id` is this a placeholder too?

Comment: No, it was the id which is mentioned immediate after the select. in parameterised query i have used place holder. the equivalent  parameterised query is : select id,date,sum(value) as distance ,(select number from table2 where id=id) as Number from Table1 where id in (?);

Comment: You might want to consider using a join rather than a subquery.

Comment: Use some table aliases. id=id is ambiguous... both for us and for the MySQL engine. Another issue is you cannot parametrize a list of values for an IN condition. One parameter for one value. I know it can be a PITA when you want a variable length list of values, but that is how parameters work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` e.g.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    date, 
    sum(value) as distance , 
    (SELECT number FROM table2 WHERE id=id) as Number 
FROM Table1 
WHERE 
    id in (1777,1778,1779) 
GROUP BY id
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: We are getting the result with this. But when using bind_param we are not getting the result for the first id(1777)  eg: $a='1777,1778,1779'; $sqlobj->bind_param('i',$a); when trying with this we are getting the result for only 1777

Comment: You **CANNOT use ONE parameter for an entire list of values**. You must use a query like ... IN (?,?,?) and bind 3 parameters.